# Rails - Delayed job - stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stack, delayed-job

The issue I am facing is similar to [this github issue](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/issues/21)

Also you can use [my comment](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_mongoid/issues/21#issuecomment-3337960) on the issue if you need more details of the error I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add an empty

```
def encode_with coder
end
```

method in your Mailer class.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/349